# Json get array object from JSON Object C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have this json string passed to my webapi

```
 string jsonstring = "{\"datamodel\": \"[{\"K1\":\"V1\",\"K2\":\"V2\"}]\"}";
```

I may have more than on pair of (K,V) inside. How do i parse this in C#  ?

I thought i could first convert my string to a JObject and get the key for datamodel from that and then use JArray to parse the K,V. But its throwing a jsonreader exception on the first line of code here

```
JObject my_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonstring.ToString());
```

and then do this..

```
 JObject data = my_obj["datamodel"].Value<JObject>();
```

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, traceback and inner exception, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the JSON string you are posting is not valid. Given your comment, you can clean up the quotes before and after the square brackets using this snippet:

```
string jsonstring = "{\"datamodel\": \"[{\"K1\":\"V1\",\"K2\":\"V2\"}]\"}";;
string jsonstringCleaned = jsonstring.Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]");
var my_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonstringCleaned);
```

Comment: If i take out the quotes like you mentioned it works..but the string i am getting is as above with the quotes... ( we can fix the quote that was missing around `\"V1\"` )

Comment: also after adding the \"V1\" and if i test it out at JSONLINT [link](http://www.jsonlint.com) it confirms as valid JSON

Comment: I have added some code to clean up the quotes around the square bracket

Comment: Yes @cableload, it will be valid JSON, however, with the quotes around the square brackets it will threat `datamodel` as a string rather than an array.

Comment: Thanks I will have to replace them then !

Comment: That works Thanks for pointing out about why the quote causes the datamodel as string !

Answer (score 1):

The code is right, but the exception you are getting is related to the formatting of your JSON string.  If you put valid JSON in this code, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are \" missing around V1 in your JSON string.
It should look like this:

```
string jsonstring = "{\"datamodel\": \"[{\"K1\":\"V1\",\"K2\":\"V2\"}]\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

First always make sure that you have a valid Json string.  A simple way to do that is paste it into a Json to C# converter tool, such as this one: http://json2csharp.com/

It may be simpler and more readable to use single quotes within your Json string if that is an option, as it avoids the need to escape the double quotes:

```
    string jsonstring = "{'datamodel': [{'K1':'V1','K2':'V2'}]}"
```

Now we deserialize the object and get the JArray.  There is no need to call  the ToString() on the JSON jsonstring string.

```
   var my_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonstring);
   var data = (JArray)my_obj["datamodel"];
```

> A better and more concise way to accomplish the same result could be to just use JObject.Parse. We can accomplish the same result with just one line of code.

```
    var data = (JArray)JObject.Parse(jsonstring)["datamodel"];
```